# OAuth consent screen in android app with OAuth2.0 using Credential Manager API

Tags: android, google-oauth, gmail-api, android-credential-manager

I am trying to request Gmail `readonly` consent in my android application, via OAuth2.0.
There are many solutions available using old Google SignIn API, but it is going to be deprecated and Credential Manager API https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/credential-manager, is now preferred approach.

I have successfully created the `Android` credentials and have the Client-id,
and I am also able to launch the system generated bottomsheet, with the following code

```
        val googleIdOption: GetGoogleIdOption = GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
            .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(filterByAuthorizedAccounts)
            .setServerClientId(CLIENT_ID)
            //.setNonce("<nonce string to use when generating a Google ID token>")
            .build()

        val credentialManager = CredentialManager.create(this)
        val request =
            GetCredentialRequest.Builder().addCredentialOption(googleIdOption).build()
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            try {
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    val result = credentialManager.getCredential(this@HomeActivity, request)
                    handleSignIn(result)
                }
            } catch (e: NoCredentialException) {
                Timber.e(e)
            } catch (e: GetCredentialException) {
                Timber.e(e)
            }
        }
```

but as soon as I select an account(which is also added as test user under cloud project), and continues, then it throws an error, instead of the consent screen that usually comes after authentication.

```
androidx.credentials.exceptions.GetCredentialCustomException: Developer console is not set up correctly.
at androidx.credentials.CredentialProviderFrameworkImpl.convertToJetpackGetException$credentials_release(CredentialProviderFrameworkImpl.kt:291)
at androidx.credentials.CredentialProviderFrameworkImpl$onGetCredential$outcome$2.onError(CredentialProviderFrameworkImpl.kt:152)
at androidx.credentials.CredentialProviderFrameworkImpl$onGetCredential$outcome$2.onError(CredentialProviderFrameworkImpl.kt:143)
at android.credentials.CredentialManager$GetCredentialTransport.lambda$onError$2(CredentialManager.java:694)
at android.credentials.CredentialManager$GetCredentialTransport.$r8$lambda$nlbYav9mLBoE6Yh1vFKCvITF3ks(Unknown Source:0)
at android.credentials.CredentialManager$GetCredentialTransport$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:6)
at androidx.credentials.CredentialManager$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.execute(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
at android.credentials.CredentialManager$GetCredentialTransport.onError(CredentialManager.java:693)
at android.credentials.IGetCredentialCallback$Stub.onTransact(IGetCredentialCallback.java:123)
at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1363)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1304)
```

Yup I have already checked `package-name` and `SHA-1` fingerprint many time, also consent screen is configured for `..gmail.readonly` scope.[Not submitted the verification, as it is in testing]. And it is not mentioned that it is needed verification to work until, it goes into production.

One more thing I tried is to replace `Android Client Id` with `Web application Client Id`. However it does allow me to sign in, but there is no consent screen afterwards.

Looking so far I think in new Credential manager API, launching consent screen is being handled by the API itself, and also I am not able to find relevant code or method in the respective package.

What is missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any type of OAuth Authorization (as compared to Authentication) is not supported by CredentialManager. For authorization, you would need to use the [Authorization APIS](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/authorize-access) directly; those APIs are part of the play-service's auth library. If you run into any issues with those APIs, please feel free to post a question.